# OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.; 42000

Tags: sql-server, odbc, olap, cube, dimension

Our cubes were working fine and were processed daily in SSMS until some Microsoft security updates were installed & the server was restarted. We receive the error message above when processing the cubes and dimensions. We already deleted the security updates but we still get the same error.

In the windows services -> SQL Server Analysis we have a service account with all the rights in SQL server (read, write, process, admin). We are working on SQL Server 2014.

We tried to:

- restart the SQL Server Analysis
- set up new accounts with read,process and admin rights on the SQL server and analysis server.
- we tried to put in the "SQL Server Analysis" to put the Local account
- create a new cube but Dimension can still not be processed.
- change the provider from "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" to "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL server" and we also checked the "allow inprocess" checkbox in SSMS in Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers.

Nothing worked of the points above. I hope someone can help us.

Error message:

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'JOIN'.; 42000. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred
> while the dimension, with the ID of
> 'd4b8c9a6-7692-4d64-bb9c-f4ac7d7d62d1', Name of 'Customer' was being
> processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while
> the 'Type' attribute of the 'Customer' dimension from the 'TestCube'
> database was being processed. Server: The current operation was
> cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
>
> Details:
>
> Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully. ...  Module:
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.OperationException
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(ImpactDetailCollection
> impacts, Boolean expectEmptyResults, Boolean throwIfError)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.Process(IMajorObject obj, ProcessType processType, Binding source, ErrorConfiguration
> errorConfig, WriteBackTableCreation writebackOption,
> XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult,
> Boolean analyzeImpactOnly)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.SendProcess(IMajorObject obj, ProcessType processType, Binding source, ErrorConfiguration
> errorConfig, WriteBackTableCreation writebackOption,
> XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult,
> Boolean analyzeImpactOnly)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ProcessableMajorObject.Process(ProcessType
> processType, ErrorConfiguration errorConfiguration,
> XmlaWarningCollection warnings)
> at TimeXtender.DataManager.CubeEngine_2005.ProcessDimension(Dimension
> dimension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:

We finally managed to fix the problem.

When running the SQL server repair it failed on SSAS with an error that indicates that the installation of SSAS was never successful so we think the files were corrupted.

Then we installed another instance of SSAS only to have 2 SSAS services. The new one was working so we deleted the old one and replaced it with a new SSAS installation. So no need reinstall the complete SQL Server.

We did backups just in case we would need them but all the cubes were automatically found by the new SSAS instance in that folder that we indicated in the installation process.
Everything was immediately working.